# Ensembling in h2o - missing models

Tags: r, machine-learning, glm, h2o, ensemble-learning

I am building an ensemble from GLM models with different regularization parameters (alpha, lambda) using the `h2o` package. When I try to build an ensemble, following the documentation:

```
ensemble <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = predictors,
                                y = response,
                                training_frame = train,
                                model_id = "ensemble",
                                base_models = list(glm_grid@model_ids))
```

Where `glm_grid@model_ids` are the models from a grid search to determine the optimal `alpha` and `lambda` regularization parameters for GLM. I receive the following error:

```
When creating a StackedEnsemble you must specify one or more models; 24 were specified but none of those were found: [list("glm_grid_model_6", glm_grid_model_11, glm_grid_model_7, glm_grid_model_9, glm_grid_model_2, glm_grid_model_21, glm_grid_model_15, glm_grid_model_0"]
```

Do you know what seems to be the issue?

EDIT: I tried following the documentation and used code analogical to that one:

```
gbm_grid <- h2o.grid(algorithm = "gbm",
                     grid_id = "gbm_grid_binomial",
                     x = x,
                     y = y,
                     training_frame = train,
                     ntrees = 10,
                     seed = 1,
                     nfolds = nfolds,
                     fold_assignment = "Modulo",
                     keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                     hyper_params = hyper_params,
                     search_criteria = search_criteria)

# Train a stacked ensemble using the GBM grid
ensemble <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = x,
                                y = y,
                                training_frame = train,
                                model_id = "ensemble_gbm_grid_binomial",
                                base_models = gbm_grid@model_ids)
```

And as per @Erin LeDell I removed the additional `list()` and it works now. However, what I would ultimately like to do is to use grids from various models, so something like:

```
ensemble <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = x,
                                y = y,
                                training_frame = train,
                                model_id = "my_ensemble_binomial",
                                base_models = list(my_gbm, my_rf))
```

EDIT2:

Solved it by using:

```
model_list <- as.list(c(glm_grid_1@model_ids,
                        glm_grid_2@model_ids))


ensemble <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = predictors,
                                y = response,
                                training_frame = train,
                                model_id = "ensemble1231",
                                base_models = model_list)
```

Comment: Please post the code used to create `glm_grid`, and the result of `list(glm_grid@model_ids)`. Also, there seems to be an issue with the quotes (") in the error message you report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `list()` wrapped around `glm_grid@model_ids` that you don't need here and that's probably the source of the error.  The `glm_grid@model_ids` object is already a list.  Do this instead:

```
ensemble <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = predictors,
                                y = response,
                                training_frame = train,
                                model_id = "ensemble",
                                base_models = glm_grid@model_ids)
```

See the R example [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html) for more information.

Comment: I have tried to do it analogically to [this](https://gist.github.com/ledell/102a24eef72bdc4ea2cd876492095684), but it is not working.

Comment: If you found my answer to be correct, can you please accept it? Thx.